# Flutter app not receiving notifications in terminated state

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-notification

I am using flutter local notification package to schedule periodic notification.
When I run the app, notifications are received for foreground and background state of the app but when the app is in terminated state, the notifications are not received.

I have provided main.dart file code below.

```
void main() async {
  
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  initializeTimeZones();

  AndroidInitializationSettings androidSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings("@mipmap/ic_launcher");

  DarwinInitializationSettings iosSettings = DarwinInitializationSettings(
    requestAlertPermission: true,
    requestBadgePermission: true,
    requestCriticalPermission: true,
    requestSoundPermission: true
  );

  InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: androidSettings,
    iOS: iosSettings
  );

  bool? initialized = await notificationsPlugin.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
    onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (response) {
      log(response.payload.toString());
    }
  );

  void showNotification() async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      "notifications-youtube",
      "YouTube Notifications",
      priority: Priority.max,
      importance: Importance.max
    );

    DarwinNotificationDetails iosDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
      presentAlert: true,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentSound: true,
    );

    NotificationDetails notiDetails = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidDetails,
      iOS: iosDetails
    );

    DateTime scheduleDate = DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: 5));

  await notificationsPlugin.periodicallyShow(0, 'repeating title',
    'repeating body', RepeatInterval.everyMinute, notiDetails,
    androidAllowWhileIdle: true);
  }
  void checkForNotification() async {
    NotificationAppLaunchDetails? details = await notificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();

    if(details != null) {
      if(details.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
        NotificationResponse? response = details.notificationResponse;

        if(response != null) {
          String? payload = response.payload;
          log("Notification Payload: $payload");
        }
      }
    }
  }

  log("Notifications: $initialized");

  @override
  void initState(){
    
    checkForNotification();
    
  }
  showNotification();

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance